# Catching an exception while using refile gem when the image isn't available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Inside of my console, it shows username@email.com.attacher_. I'm pretty sure the refile isn't working because the image for the user is not there. But, how would I set it to process the method block when file is nil?

```
  module MessagesHelper

      def recipients_options
        s = ''
        users = User.all + BizUser.all; users.each do |user|
          s << "<option value='#{user.id}'
    data-img-src='#{attachment_url(@user, user.email, :profile_avatar,
    :fill, 50, 50)}'>#{user.username}</option>"
        end
        s.html_safe
      end
    end
```

Here is the error showing in my log file

```
NoMethodError in Messages#new
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `profile_avatar_attacher' for nil:NilClass):
     9:   <div class="row">
    10:     <div class="large-5 medium-5 small-4 columns" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    11:       <%= label_tag 'recipients', 'Choose recipients' %>
    12:       <%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options, multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
    13:     </div>
    14:   </div>
    15:   <div class="row">
  app/helpers/messages_helper.rb:6:in `block in recipients_options'


module MessagesHelper

  def recipients_options
    s = ''
    users = User.all + BizUser.all; users.each do |user|
      s << "<option value='#{user.id}' data-img-src='#{attachment_url(@user, :profile_avatar, :fill, 30, 30)}'>#{user.username}</option>"
    end
    s.html_safe
  end
end
```

ApplicationHelper for avatar method

```
def avatar_for_user
    image_tag attachment_url(@user, :profile_avatar, :fill, 30, 30)
  end
```

I'm receiving an error in the participants.html.erb partial as well

```
<% conversation.participants.each do |participant| %>
    <% unless participant == current_user %>
        <%= avatar_for_user participant %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: We need more info. What is the desired result and what are you actually getting? Also: I recommend using Rails' content tag helpers instead of hand-made HTML.

Comment: I need to pass the email, profile avatar and username to Chose It for querying users for my messaging feature. This is the reason why I built it the way you see it.

Comment: That's not what I asked. What is the result you're after and what is it that you're actually getting? The way you're constructing HTML using string interpolation exposes you to injection attacks.

Comment: I provided you with all of the code related to it's implementation that could be the source of the error.

Comment: It seems as if data-img-src='#{attachment_url(@user, :profile_avatar, :fill, 30, 30)} is not passing correctly into the method's string. I think gravatar automatically sets a default avatar while refile doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the `user` local variable and the `@user` instance variable.

In `recipients_options` you call

```
attachment_url(@user :profile_avatar, :fill, 30, 30)
```

You're rendering the same attachment (the one for `@user`) for every option.

I suspect you want to call

```
attachment_url(user, :profile_avatar, :fill, 30, 30)
```

Thus rendering the attachment for each user.

The reason that you're getting the NoMethod-error seems to be that the `@user` variable is nil.

Also, `avatar_for_user` seems strange. You define it with no argument but pass it a user in the partial.

Comment: The gravatar version of this method requires multiple parameters. This approach is easier to manage across app compared to the original. I was just having trouble filling the void. I'll check this solution out shortly. Thank you for your support so far.

Comment: It tells me that I have 3 extra arguments when I swap out the code <%= avatar_for message.sender, 45, message.sender.username %> I'm speaking to a buddy who normally uses gravatar to see if he can help. I'll post my findings when I figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean "when I swap out the code". Where's this `avatar_for` method defined? There are multiple gravatar gems from what I can see, are you using any of them? Why are you mixing up gravatar and Refile? Are you using Refile to store cached Gravatar images?

Comment: No, I'm using refile to attach avatars and other photos related to the user model within the app.

Comment: Then why this talk about gravatar?

Comment: The original solution included the implementation of it. I refactored to support refile instead. I just got word that refile isn't acting properly, and we will use paperclip instead of gravatar.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the gem is failing to attach files on certain instances.